# Python 3.11 installing repl-cli: setuptools not found even it's installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, replit, python-3.11

That's it. I am installing repl-cli but it's giving "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'".

I tried:

```
pip install setuptools
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (67.1.0)
```

And then:

```
 pip install repl-cli
 .
 . Tons of installation verbose
 .
RROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 415, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 373, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 213, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_updated_criteria(candidate)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 204, in _get_updated_criteria
    self._add_to_criteria(criteria, requirement, parent=candidate)
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
                ^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 231, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 491, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 577, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 69, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 48, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._install_build_reqs(finder)
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 118, in _install_build_reqs
    build_reqs = self._get_build_requires_wheel()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 95, in _get_build_requires_wheel
    return backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 701, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return super().get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings=cs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 166, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 321, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
pip._vendor.pyproject_hooks._impl.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
    obj = import_module(mod_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

Just don't know what to do. I am this whole day trying to install packages and searching errors on google. I already solved at leats 7 error messages for installing this today and I can't fix this one alone.

Comment: Perhaps try the `--user` flag to pip, so it installs in your `~/.local` directory?

Comment: I think already tried it: Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/bitte/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (67.1.0)

Comment: No, I meant for installing `repl-cli`.

Comment: Oh sorry. But it doesn't change nothing.